# Зачем нужно приведение указателя?

Tags: c++, c

Есть такой код:

```
int *i=(int*)malloc(50*sizeof(int));
```

У меня 2 вопроса:

1)Зачем нужно явное приведение типа (int*)?Что происходит когда мы явно пишем

2)Шилдт пишет про то что,когда мы пишем sizeof(int),мы организовываем машинонезависимость.В чем заключается эта независимость?Размер int в разных системах разный?

Comment: 1) чтобы не было неявного приведения типа 2) может быть и разный

Comment: ну а для чего вообще нужно это приведение?ну присвоим мы указателю адрес этой выделенной памяти,все равно же будем работать как с типом int

Comment: В С он и не нужен..

Comment: а зачем так сделали в с++?)

Comment: Тому было [множество причин](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/) -)

Comment: @avp *...Alternatives... Throwing yourself into an active volcano.* — это же реклама суицида! И куда только роскомнадзор смотрит?!

Comment: Ну почитайте про преимущества языков со строгой типизацией.

Answer (score 2):

Каст `(int *)` меняет тип указателя с `void *` на `int *`, значение указателя при этом не меняется. В C то же самое происходит автоматически и без каста (каст не нужен), а в С++ без каста не скомпилируется (потому что типы указателей не совпадают).

> Размер int в разных системах разный?

Теоретически может быть разный, но чаще всего `int` 4-байтовый.

Comment: ок,a sizeof(тип) определяется на моменте компиляции или в моменте выполнения программы ?

Comment: @Whitehorse Здесь во время компиляции. В С++ всегда во время компиляции. В С во время компиляции, если только его не применить к массиву переменной длины (которых в С++ нет).

Comment: По крайней мере g++ позволяет использовать VLA. Например: `int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  int a[ac];

  printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(a));
}` компилируется и работает в g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0